# Parameter server dictionary lookups in rosjava

Tags: rosparam, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got file robot.yaml with massive of parameters

```
nxt_robot:
  - type: motor
    name: r_wheel_joint
    port: PORT_A
    desired_frequency: 20.0

  - type: motor
    name: l_wheel_joint
    port: PORT_B
    desired_frequency: 20.0

  - type: ultrasonic
    frame_id: ultrasonic_link
    name: ultrasonic_sensor
    port: PORT_2
    spread_angle: 0.2
    min_range: 0.01
    max_range: 2.5
    desired_frequency: 5.0
```

In Python I read parameters so:

```
config = rospy.get_param("~nxt_robot")
for c in config:
    rospy.loginfo("Creating %s with name %s on %s",c['type'],c['name'],c['port'])
```

How to do it in rosjava?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11359/parameter-server-dictionary-lookups-in-rosjava/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to look up a subtree of parameters in rosjava. It's described with an example on the wiki here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Overview/Parameters

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I've been able to find, rosjava does not support dictionary lookups from the parameter server. C++ also lacks this ability. You can look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Overview/Parameters) for some information on rosjava parameters.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2